Python flask code executing in terminal instead of launching html webpage
In the main code there is a class in which there are 4 functions. the code is about Audio to Sign Language Conversion.  I imported the class in another flask code. but instead of launching the html webpage, the function executes in the terminal.
https://github.com/dev4500/check/tree/main/chck
I tried changing the port number for flask to 5001. I thought it would launch the html webpage in the browser to take user input (audio) from there and then display the sign language images on the html webpage.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Your code works perfectly fine. You just need to copy the link of the local hosted website from the terminal and open it in any browser.
The link will look like this: http://127.0.0.1:5000/
Here is the output of the terminal:
PS C:\Users\Moccisor> & C:/Python312/python.exe c:/Users/Moccisor/Desktop/check-main/chck/app.py
 * Serving Flask app 'app'
 * Debug mode: on
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 653-528-385

